# What does an exclamation mark in "git show-branch" mean?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm just getting started with git. If I do a 'git show-branch', it shows me branch divergence graphically. What do the exclamation marks above the `---` separator mean vs the asterisk?

```
XXXXX@XXXXX gittest % git show-branch
* [Branch1] Adding third file to Branch1
 ! [feature/new-feature] Adding second file to master branch
  ! [master] Adding second file to master branch
---
*   [Branch1] Adding third file to Branch1
*   [Branch1^] Branch 1 file two
*   [Branch1~2] Branch1 first commit
 ++ [feature/new-feature] Adding second file to master branch
*++ [Branch1~3] Initial commit
XXXXX@XXXXX gittest %
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch#_output

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri This has nothing in common with aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the official doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch#_output)

> Given N , the first N lines are the one-line description from their commit message. The branch head that is pointed at by $GIT_DIR/HEAD is prefixed with an asterisk * character ***while other heads are prefixed with a ! character***.